# Better practices for choosing partitioning strategies on Greenplum DB [Big Data]

Tags: database, bigdata, database-performance, greenplum

I need to know if anyone has any general guidelines (beyond trial and error), for defining a good strategy for optimal partitioning / indexing for a range of query types in Greenplum?

Greenplum has some advice on their admin guide... But truth is, it's almost a copy paste from the postgres docs, and while some of it's advice seems obvious (IE: partition when a table is too big to fit in memory), it's just not enough to define a good strategy to achieve this.

Usually Greenplum databases have very large tables (ranging over hundreds of GBs), and although hardware is specifically chosen for this kind of use, most of the times I've encountered trouble when it comes to really large databases (IE: once had a database with a 60 field table and over 2 thousand million rows that kept increasing it's size by 4-8 million registries a day).

I know there are some techniques on choosing the proper partition, like selecting predictable ranges that will be separated in almost equal sizes (Like date ranges). But there's also the fact that while with any other database I try to rely on indexes, Greenplum completely discourages them by giving a bigger weight to some settings, like its random page cost so that indexes are not used at all.

But I've read some situations where this is completely counter productive: Imagine you have three nodes each of 64GB ram, according to GP you shouldn't partition until the tables are over 192, but since indexes are not used you'll end up seq scanning up to 64gb per node! --- Although this can still be fast, if you enforce index use you can go down from over 20 seconds to just milliseconds.

Another known case is that, when partitioning, the overhead makes the query a lot slower than it should be.

**So, back to the original question:**
Does anyone have any good, firm advice on how to define your partitioning/indexing strategy?
With some of our ETL's the test queries from source can take up from half to a full hour, so trail and error really pushes back productivity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question depends less on math & more on how your users will access the table.  For date-range partitioning, if users normally look for a day's worth of data, then daily partitions can make sense.  If users normally query over longer date ranges, then daily partitions will just add overhead.  Each partition or sub-partition in a Greenplum DB table is treated as a separate table (and therefore a separate file on the filesystem), so the more partitions you have to scan to satisfy a query, the more open files you need to access.  Understand how your users want to access the data, and that will give you better clues about possible partitioning strategies.

A hybrid partitioning strategy can be useful as well.  Certain use cases would favor a table where there are daily partitions for the most recent week/month, and then have older partitions cover longer timeframes since they are accessed less often, and usually for reporting/analytics queries versus row lookups or similar.

As far as indexing goes, while Greenplum DB's optimizer favors table scans over index access there are places where indexes make sense.  I have had good luck with bitmap indexes in some cases.

Unfortunately tuning GPDB is still an art form just like other databases, so a certain amount of trial & error is probably unavoidable.